# Dropdown not showing the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i have coded.

```
$(document).on("change", "#keyDropDown, #valueOfKey", function() {
    //var chosenKey = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    var chosenKey = $("#keyDropDown").val();
    var chosenValue = $("#valueOfKey").val();
    var data = { key: chosenKey, value: chosenValue };

    $.ajax({
        url: "value_choices",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

DropDown1 is showing the selected option.It is working fine but in DropDown2 as soon as i select any option other than the first option, DropDown2 quickly gets back to first option.It is not showing the selected option.

**Incase you need to see my entire code it is shown below.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).on("change", "#keyDropDown, #valueOfKey", function() {
    //var chosenKey = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    var chosenKey = $("#keyDropDown").val();
    var chosenValue = $("#valueOfKey").val();
    var data = { key: chosenKey, value: chosenValue };

    $.ajax({
        url: "value_choices",
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
        if (response.data) {
            var valueDropDown = $("#valueOfKey");
            valueDropDown.empty();
            for (var item of response.data) {
            valueDropDown.append(
                "<option value=" + item + ">" + item + "</option>"
            );
            }
        }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = "";
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = "Not connect.\n Verify Network.";
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = "Requested page not found. [404]";
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = "Internal Server Error [500].";
        } else if (exception === "parsererror") {
            msg = "Requested JSON parse failed.";
        } else if (exception === "timeout") {
            msg = "Time out error.";
        } else if (exception === "abort") {
            msg = "Ajax request aborted.";
        } else {
            msg = "Uncaught Error.\n" + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        $("#post").html(msg);
        }
    });
});   
</script>
```

HTML part of my code.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% if user.Journey_Shaping or user.is_superuser %}
{% load static %}
<div id="content">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form >
<div>
<input type="text" name="testPersonaName">
<br><br><br>
<select id="keyDropDown">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="ip">ip</option>
    <option value="country">Country</option>
    <option value="city">City</option>
    <option value="region">Region</option>
    <option value="device">Device</option>
    <option value="visits">Visits</option>
    <option value="page">Pages Visited</option>
    <option value="user_id">User Id</option>
    <option value="browser">Browser</option>

 </select>
 <select id="valueOfKey" name="myvalue"></select>
 <input type="submit" name="Save">
 </div>
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  // This is the script that i have given above in my question details.  
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

**Django view**

```
class ValueChoicesView(View):
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    key = request.GET.get('key')
    if key is None:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
            "error": "Field 'key' is required."
        }), content_type='application/json')
    # another validation would be if the key belongs in `ModelA`

    if key == 'page':
        data = []
        key_qs = Page.objects.all().values(key)


        for item in key_qs:
            if item[key] not in data:
                data.append(item[key])

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": data}), content_type="application/json")

    else:

        data = []
        key_qs = VisitorInfo.objects.all().values(key)

        for item in key_qs:
            if item[key] not in data:
                data.append(item[key])

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"data": data}), content_type="application/json")
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML part for the drop down?

Comment: I have updated my question details @Ahmad . You may now see the html part.

Comment: You're using an ID selector in your jQuery (`#`), you must use class selector (`.`) if you want `.on()` to select more that 1 element. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53646175/1155833). You must also set classes instead of ID's in your HTML.

Comment: Based on comment on my answer below, you're trying something different as the issue you're describing. The code shows something else again. Could you edit in, very clearly, what it is that you're trying to achieve with your code? Currently you have a bunch of mistakes in the code, which, at least for me, muddles your intentions.

Comment: I am also adding my django view which may help you in knowing how things are going on. @rkeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get your elements by class, not by id.

[Getting by class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Example: `$(".myClass")`

---

[Docs for getting by ID](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

> Calling jQuery() (or $()) with an id selector as its argument will return a jQuery object containing a collection of ***either zero or one DOM element***.

Example: `$("#myId")`

---

Based on discussion on question and this answer:

#### Edit

```
// Set "on" listener for "change" event on single element, identified by id: keyDropDown
$(document).on("change", "#keyDropDown", function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "value_choices",
        type: "GET",
        data: {key: $(this).val()}, // $(this) is the first dropdown element, we need it's value
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.data) {
                var secondDropdown = $("#valueOfKey"); // select 2nd dropdown
                secondDropdown.empty();                // empty dropdown

                for (var item of response.data) {      // loop response & create options
                    secondDropdown.append(
                        "<option value=" + item + ">" + item + "</option>"
                    );
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            // error handling
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have used class now but It's still showing the same behavior.Please @rkeet help me fix this.

Comment: What is it you're expecting? Every time a `change` happens on a dropdown with id `keyDropDown`, you're setting data to `#valueOfKey` and triggering the callback function (which in turn gets some data and repopulates the second dropdown). Have you read the [jQuery .on docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)? I do believe you should remove the `$.ajax` call from the callback and trigger that: 1 - on startup of the page to populate dynamically OR: 2 - trigger it on change of dropdown 1, but then you should use ID's and remove the 3rd parameter and inspect your [..]

Comment: ... inspect your `response.data` and handle accordingly to the response, not generically for the setup - which is what you're doing at the moment and it's causing your issues.

Comment: Ok @rkeet. I describe you what the situation is. On my test_page.html, i have text field where i am getting some input from the user. Next there are two dropdowns i.e DropDown1 and DropDown2 . For each option in DropDown1 , there are some values present in a django model. Based on option selected in DropDown1 , all the values related to that selected option will be shown as options in DropDown2. Then I will select any one option from DropDown2 and press the submit button which will store all these values in my database.......

Comment: .... For example:- First I will enter 'RKEET' in textfield of the html form.Then from DropDown1 suppose I select Country.Now as soon as i select country , DropDown2 will populate with the countries saved in my django Model.Say Options for Country are Russia, India , France and Canada etc. Now when I select Canada , DrowDown2 quickly gets back to first option i.e Russia and doesn't show the selected value i.e Russia.I hope i have explained properly.Please tell me if you need some more details. @rkeet

Comment: Thanks a lot @rkeet. You really saved me brother. I wish i could thank you in person.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me

```
$(".class_name").val(value).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This inside your ajax Success :

```
if(response.data) {
   var valueDropDown = $('#valueOfKey');
   valueDropDown.html();

   var dropDown = '<option value="">Select Dropdown</option>';
   $.each(response.data, function(item) {
      dropDown += '<option>' + item + '</option>';
   }

   valueDropDown.html(dropDown);
}
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Brother @MDJubairMizan , I tried your code but this didn't help. In my code when i select any option from DropDown1 , options in DrowDown are shown according to that. But when i used your code. DropDown2 stopped showing options based on option selected in DropDown1. Anyways very thank you that you took time to help me. If you may help me fix this problem, I will be highly obliged.

Comment: Dear @AshokKumar . Can you show me your query then i can tell you what's going on . As you told Dropdown1 is working fine and you don't get data on selected item , I think this is happends based on your return query

Comment: Brother i have updated my question details. Now i have provided django view which is fetching data from django model based on the option selected in DropDown1. Thanks @MDJubairMizan

Comment: As your provided code you are fixed your fetch record based on page and else data wise . Make sure your selecting key record has on your key_qs = VisitorInfo.objects.all().values(key) Model